# Swing GUI to show moving images

Tags: java, image, swing

How should I show file transfer using moving images in Swing?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an animated GIF (unless you want it to be influenced by how much of it has transferred). [This](http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/jfc-swing/use-animated-gif-image-in-jfc-swing-application) is a good example.